# First order logic, build a model to prove a formula.

Tags: first-order-logic

This is a homework question, and my mind is working a little backwards today. So I'm asking for help on a easy question, so that I can unravel the harder ones on my own.

I need to build a model for a formula so that it become true, the domain we will be using is {1,2}

∀x∀yRxy

Now I can do the oposite and prove the formula wrong by interpeting the relation symbol R as Ø, as one example.
I can't make a bigger-than formula because the set in constrained to {1,2}

Anyone got a hint?

Hope I made it clear enough

Comment: Is your formula $\forall x \forall y R(x,y)$?

Comment: Hi, the formula as given is: ∀x∀yRxy

Comment: There are only 16 binary operations on the 2-element set {1,2}. Determine the truth value of your formula in each of those 16 models. You will find that there is just one in which it's true.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking correctly, and you are using the language $\{R\}$, you have no choice but to let $R=\{1,2\}^2$. If you can convince yourself that this is the only way to make the model satisfy the formula, you've understood everything there is to say about this problem.

Comment: @BrettFrankel I suspect that your comment is as complete an answer as this question merits. I therefore suggest you make it one.

Answer (score 1):

[Brett Frankel said](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552007/first-order-logic-build-a-model-to-prove-a-formula#comment1174459_552007) everything in a comment:

> If I understand what you're asking correctly, and you are using the language $\{R\}$, you have no choice but to let $R=\{1,2\}^2$. If you can convince yourself that this is the only way to make the model satisfy the formula, you've understood everything there is to say about this problem.